# Advanced query based on join

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema looks like this:

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));


create table ads(
  ad_id int,
  ad_name varchar(10)
);

create table ads_insight(
   id int,
   ad_id int,
   date date, 
   ad_clicks int
 );
create table products(
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);
create table products_insight(
    id int,
    product_id int, 
    sale int, 
    date date
);
create table ads_products(
    ad_id int,
    product_id int
);
                                    

                                    
insert into ads(ad_id, ad_name) values
  (1,'ad1'),
  (2,'ad2'),
  (3,'ad3');
 
 
insert into ads_insight(id, ad_id, date, ad_clicks) values
    (1, 1, '2021-04-25', 1),
    (3, 1, '2021-04-23', 2),
    (4, 1, '2021-04-22', 8),
    (5, 2, '2021-04-25', 6),
    (6, 2, '2021-03-03', 7);


insert into products(id, name) values
    (1,'prod1'),
    (2,'prod2'),
    (3,'prod3'),
    (4,'prod4'),
    (5,'prod5');
                                        
insert into ads_products (ad_id, product_id) values 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1);
insert into products_insight(id, product_id, sale, date) values
    (1, 1, 10, '2021-04-25'),
    (2, 1, 13, '2021-04-24'),
    (3, 1, 15, '2021-04-23'),
    (4, 1, 14, '2021-04-22'),
    (5, 1, 17, '2021-04-21'),
    (6, 1, 15, '2021-04-20'),
    (7, 1, 13, '2021-04-19'),
    (8, 2, 15, '2021-04-25');
```

Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfXrNqQC6wVFYM6NTNX7oJ/11)

A quick explanation of schema:
I have ads:

1. each ad has insights, which tell us when a certain ad was active(=> ad_clicks has to be > 0).
2. each ad has products(many2many - `ads_products` table). Each product has `products_insight` which tells us how many sales that product generated on a certain day.

Now I want to get all ads from the time range `2021-04-20` - `2021-04-25` which had `ad_clicks` > 0 (which I have done) AND count how many sales each ad has generated when it was active. So count sale only if the ad has ad_insight and ad_clicks > 0.

My query looks like this:

```sql
SET @from_date = '2021-04-20';
SET @to_date = '2021-04-25';

SELECT 
    ads.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(ad_clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks
    FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN products_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id 
WHERE ad_clicks>0;
```

And it generates the following result:

```
| ad_name | clicks | product_sale | products          |
| ------- | ------ | ------------ | ----------------- |
| ad1     | 11     | 99           | prod1,prod2       |
| ad2     | 6      | 15           | prod2,prod3,prod4 |
```

But I want this(there is a difference in the `product_sale` column)

```
| ad_name | clicks | product_sale | products          |
| ------- | ------ | ------------ | ----------------- |
| ad1     | 11     | 54           | prod1,prod2       |
| ad2     | 6      | 15           | prod2,prod3,prod4 |
```

`54` because it counts only rows with id: `1,3,4` from `products_insight` because in these days ad with id `1` was active. (active means that there is a row in `ads_insight` table.

Comment: How 39?  please explain which `products_insight` rows count and why.

Comment: it counts only rows with id: `1,3,4` from `products_insight` because in these days ad with id `1` was active. (active means that there is a row in `ads_insight` table.

Comment: Why row 8 is not counted? You group by ad.id and ad.id=1 is about products 1 and 2. Why product 2 sale shouldn't be counted? My guess is you need 54 for ad.id=1.

Comment: Ah, there was an error, now it is correrct.

Comment: I notice that you persist in changing the SQL mode.  That suggests to me that you are not trying to learn SQL properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add same date conition in your `pi` subquery. It will effectively make it inner JOIN

```
..
    (SELECT ap.ad_id, sum(pi.sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    JOIN ads_insight AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
        AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    JOIN products_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id AND pi.date = ai.date 
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id) as pi ..
```

The whole query, all the rest is from the original one

```
SET @from_date = '2021-04-20';
SET @to_date = '2021-04-25';

SELECT 
    ads.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(ad_clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks
    FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, sum(pi.sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    JOIN ads_insight AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
        AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    JOIN products_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id AND pi.date = ai.date 
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id 
WHERE ad_clicks>0;
```

[The fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rEYvG9C8kRpKmhY7i3MhhS/0)

Comment: So please write the final query

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EXISTS clause while aggregating the product sales like below to filter based on date and the ad_id

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN products_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM ads_insight ai 
        WHERE ai.date=pi.date AND ai.ad_id =  ap.ad_id)
    GROUP BY ad_id ) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
```

[image: Result]

The final query would like this

```
SET @from_date = '2021-04-20';
SET @to_date = '2021-04-25';

SELECT 
    ads.ad_name, 
    IFNULL(ad_clicks, 0) AS clicks, 
    IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, 
    IFNULL(products, '') AS products
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(ad_clicks) AS ad_clicks
    FROM ads_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN products_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM ads_insight ai 
        WHERE ai.date=pi.date AND ai.ad_id =  ap.ad_id)
    AND date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ads.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ap.ad_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) AS products
    FROM ads_products AS ap 
    JOIN products AS p ON ap.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY ap.ad_id
) AS p ON ads.ad_id = p.ad_id 
WHERE ad_clicks>0;
```

Comment: Can you paste final query?

Comment: As EXISTS depends on `pi.date` , `LEFT JOIN  products_insight AS pi` becames INNER, nulls are excluded